# Matrix manipulation

Tags: matrices

While studying PageRank, I came across the following equation in an example:

$$(A,B,C,D) = (A,B,C,D)
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
It says that it can be read off that $C = D/3$. This I can understand.

But in the next statement, 
$$(A,B,C,D) = (A,B,C,D)
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/3+1/6 & 1/3+1/6 & 1/3 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
This I do not understand? I've been thinking a lot, please tell me how this is true. Thanks!

edit: We are actually trying to compute A,B,C and D such that this is true. The exact statement reads "We can straightaway read off the equality C=D/3. Then we can eliminate C by first expressing C in terms of D on the right-hand side of the equations."

Comment: This looks like a step in computing the steady-state distribution of the matrix, which will be a left-eigenvector of $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of the product is a linear combination of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. The third row of the matrix gives the coefficients of $C$ in each element of the product, and the fourth row has the coefficients of $D$. Since $C=D/3$, you can fold the third row into the fourth by adding $1/3$ times the third row to the fourth and zeroing out the third. In effect, you’ve substituted $3D$ for $C$ in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm now what is said in your text.

The main idea is to "cast" your problem into an eigenvalue-eigenvector issue by transposing your equations:

- **First matricial equation:**  Let us transpose equation $(A B C D)=(A B C D)M_1 \ \iff \ V=VM_1$ in order to recognize, into the new form, i.e.,:

$$M_1^TV^T=1V^T \ \ \text{ with } \ \ \  V^T:=\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\end{pmatrix}$$

an eigenvalue-eigenvector issue with eigenvalue $1$.

Indeed, there is no problem with eigenvalue 1, because this first matrix $M_1^T$ has characteristic polynomial

$$x^4-\tfrac{7}{12}x^2-\tfrac{1}{3}x-\tfrac{1}{12}$$

thus has eigenvalue 1 with order of multiplicity 1.

The associated eigenvector is any nonzero vector proportional to $$\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$ with its third component $C$ is the third of its fourth component $D$.

- **Second matricial equation:** same operations: the characteristic polynomial of $M_2^T$ is:

$$x^4-\tfrac{3}{4}x^2-\tfrac{1}{4}x$$

with eigenvalue 1, multiplicity 1, and associated eigenvector(s), any multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}$ (the same one as before) (you can check it).

Comment on your last questions: If I remember well, the "Google rank algorithm" proceed by successive rank one modifications. Here, you proceed from matrix $M_1$ to matrix $M_2$ by adding a rank 2 matrix:

$$M_2=M_1+\begin{pmatrix}0 &0\\
0&0\\
1 &0\\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: We assume that 1 is an eigenvalue and that it is a simple eigenvalue. I'm confusing something very simple perhaps

Comment: Is the present state of my answer understandable ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confusing somewhere. If you multiple the right hand side you will get something like (P, Q, A*0+B*0+C*0+D*1/3, S) = (P, Q, D/3, S). Comparing this to left hand side gives C = D/3. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Pardon me, I am very sorry, I had forgotten to transpose this matrix. I correct my answer, and I look at the second matrix.

Comment: I have added something at the end in connection with updates by rank one matrices. Beyond that, I think that doing calculations in this particular case is one thing, recognizing the general issues (eigenvalue-eigenvectors issues with eigenvalues 1 as in Markov processes) is another... I wish that what I have done will be of some utility in the future for you...